# How to add image icon in react bootstrap switch button?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[Want this type of switch button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ7Jk.png)

```
<BootstrapSwitchButton



onChange={onhandleswitch}
```

checked={swtich}
onlabel={`<img src="${logo}"/>`}
offlabel={`<img src="${logo}"/>`}

/>

tried above approach but still got no image instead i got complete img tag as text like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcTc9.png)

I just want to add image icon in switch button for on and off both

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the value of the src attribute is literally `"${logo}"`.
To make use of variables inside a string, you'll have to replace the double-quotes - `"` with backticks - `` ` ``

Here are two solutions that you can use:

1. `` src=`${logo}` ``
2. `src={logo}`